# I need help figuring out why current program does not work properly

Tags: c++, arrays, getline

I am struggling to make this program work for my C++ course. Every time that I go to input a persons name, the program tells me that is invalid. Any help looking over my program would be greatly appreciated. The program needs to pull names and gpas from out of a txt file named mystudents.txt.

**Program instructions:**

The attached source code (Lab6.cpp) contains an incomplete program and its design.  For this lab, you will be completing the three functions set_gpa, get_gpa, and read_students.  Main function does not need to be modified, though you may make changes to main in order to test your other functions.

Following the design in Lab6.cpp, write code to complete the functions so that the three functions will work as specified.  Your main function can be modified for additional testing, but the functions must work as specified independent of the main function.

**My current program which i have been working on:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


void set_gpa(string names[], double gpas[], int arraysize, double newgrade);
double get_gpa(string names[], double gpas[], int arraysize);
void read_students(string names[], double gpas[], int arraysize, stringfilename);



//
const int NUMSTU = 20;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    string studentnames[NUMSTU];
    double gpas[NUMSTU];
    string studentfile = "mystudents.txt";
    double studentgpa;

    read_students(studentnames, gpas, NUMSTU, studentfile);
    studentgpa = get_gpa(studentnames, gpas, NUMSTU);
    cout << "Got GPA of:  " << studentgpa << endl;
    set_gpa(studentnames, gpas, NUMSTU, 3.9);
    studentgpa = get_gpa(studentnames, gpas, NUMSTU);
    cout << "Got GPA of:  " << studentgpa << endl;

    return 0;
}


//set_gpa
//Purpose:  Get input of a student's name and, after validation, set that student's GPA to a given value.
//Preconditions:  Arrays of student names and gpas in parallel, the size of the array, and the grade.
//Postconditions:  Change the gpa of the validated student to the given value
void set_gpa(string names[], double gpas[], int arraysize, double newgrade){
   int counter = 0;
   bool studentnotfound = true;
   string nextname;
   double theirgpa;
    //1.  Get input of a student's name.
        cout << "Please input a students name" << endl;
        getline(cin, nextname);
    //2.  Search for the student's name in the array
        for(int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++){
            //2.1 Are you waldo?
            if(nextname == names[i]){
                studentnotfound = false;
                theirgpa = gpas[i];
            }
        }
        //3.  Until student's name has been located in the array:
        while(studentnotfound){
    //3.1     Inform user that the name was invalid.
            cout << "invalid name." << endl;
    //3.2     Get input of a student's name.
            cout << "Please input a  students name" << endl;
            getline(cin, nextname);
    //3.3     Search for the student's name in the array
            for(int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++){
    //4.  Store the student's new GPA in the array
            if(nextname == names[i]){
            gpas[i] = newgrade;
            }
        }
    }
        return;
}

//get_gpa
//Purpose:  Get input of a student's name and, after validation, return that student's GPA
//Preconditions:  Arrays of student names and gpas in parallel, the size of the array, and the grade.
//Postconditions:  Return the gpa of the validated student
double get_gpa(string names[], double gpas[], int arraysize){
   int counter = 0;
   bool studentnotfound = true;
   string nextname;
   double theirgpa;
    //1.  Get input of a student's name.
        cout << "Please input a students name" << endl;
        getline(cin, nextname);
    //2.  Search for the student's name in the array
        for(int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++){
            //2.1 Are you waldo?
            if(nextname == names[i]){
                studentnotfound = false;
                theirgpa = gpas[i];
            }
        }

        while(studentnotfound){
    //3.  Until student's name has been located in the array:
    //3.1     Inform user that the name was invalid.
            cout << "invalid name." << endl;
    //3.2     Get input of a student's name.
            cout << "Please input a students name" << endl;
            getline(cin, nextname);
    //3.3     Search for the student's name in the array
            for(int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++){
            //2.1 Are you waldo?
            if(nextname == names[i]){
                studentnotfound = false;
            }
            }
        }
    //4.  Return the student's GPA
    return theirgpa;
}

//read_students
//Purpose:  Store student names and gpas in two parallel arrays from an input file
//Preconditions:  empty arrays to store student names and gpas, the size of the arrays, and a file name
//Postconditions:  store the names and gpas of students into the array arguments up to the maximum size of the arrays
void read_students(string names[], double gpas[], int arraysize, string filename){
    string nextname;
    double nextgpa;
    ifstream infile;
    char nextchar;

    int counter = 0;
    //1.  Open file with the given filename
            infile.open(filename.c_str());
    //2.  Try to read a student's name on the next line
            getline(infile, nextname);
    //3.  Try to read a student's GPA on the next line
            infile >> nextgpa;
    //4.  Until we fail to read a student or run out of array space:
                while(infile && counter < arraysize){
    //4.1     Store the student's name in the array
                    names[counter] = nextname;
    //4.2     Store the student's gpa in the array
                    gpas[counter] = nextgpa;
    //4.3     Try to read a student's name on the next line
                    infile.get(nextchar);
                    getline(infile, nextname);
    //4.4     Try to read a student's GPA on the next line
                    infile >> nextgpa;

    //4.5     Add one to the line counter
                    counter ++;
                }
                infile.close();

}
```

**Example of a mystudents.txt, of which the file needs to pull gpas and names from**

```
billy bob
4.0    
johnny smith
3.1
Craig Bean
1.2
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You simply forgot to set `studentnotfound` to false once the name is found to be valid.

Comment: Delete the forward declarations, move `main` to the bottom of the file, and marvel at half of your errors magically vanishing. While I think `stringfilename` is just a typo, unnecessary forward declarations are just more code that can go wrong with zero added value.

Comment: Ran your code through the compiler. It's probably telling you something important about `theirgpa`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the `read_students` function to make sure that you are actually successfully opening the file:

```
infile.open(filename.c_str());
if (infile.fail()) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Failed to open file: " + filename);
}
```